# Python Prime Problem

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, primes, python

Your challenge is to write a Python program to print all the primes (separated by whitespace) less than a given integer `N` with an asterisk (`*`) next to each twin prime in **ONE statement**. A [twin prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) is a prime number that is either two more or two less than another prime.

All output should be to stdout and input should be read from stdin. (Hardcoding outputs is allowed, but it is not likely to result in very short code.)

Shortest code wins!

For the less restricted version of the challenge for all languages, click [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219980/primes-and-twin-primes).

### Input

- `N` is always one of 50, 100, 1000, 1000000, or 10000000

### Output

- Possible output for input `12` could be

  ```
  2 3* 5* 7* 11*
  ```

  (However, the input will never be 12, as specified above. Your program need not work for this input.)

### Restrictions

- No new lines or semicolons

  Do not use eval or exec

Comment: "one statement" - does that allow something like `for i in []: print(i)` or not? It's technically a compound statement, which contains another one, and it doesn't have any  newlines or semicolons...

Comment: @pxeger Yes, that is allowed.

Comment: Requiring input to be taken from stdin and written to stdout generally isn't recommended here because it makes the challenge less about solving the problem and more about boring I/O plumbing/implementation. I'd recommend using the [standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)

Comment: @pxeger I thought it would be more consistent that way. And there is only one input.

Comment: I'd very strongly recommend changing the rules; this makes the challenge significantly less attractive. Also I didn't see you posted in the sandbox, [but you should generally leave it in for a few days at least](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7296)

Comment: @user101295 you have to post challenge in Sandbox before you post it here, and you should keep it at least 72 hours there, but now don't delete this challenge, because an answer has been already posted, deletion of this challenge will remove the contributions too, from next time post challenge to Sanbox before here, Thanks!

Comment: @Wasif First of all, no, you don't *have* to post in the Sandbox, it's just highly recommended for users without much challenge writing experience (and also for everyone who do). Furthermore, the OP can't delete the challenge as there is a positively scoring answer, so the system prevents deletion.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I was not saying to post all challenges to Sandbox after this, I was just asking the OP to not post this one to Sandbox, because this one has been already posted here. Also thank you for clarifying that questions with positive scored answer cannot be deleted!

Comment: The base challenge is awesome, Try to make the challenge open for all languages, then it will be nicely attractive and well defined and the vote meter will raise higher!

Comment: @Wasif I've created a less restricted version of the challenge [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219980/primes-and-twin-primes).

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of the less restricted version, as the [restricted-source] part of the challenge does not significantly change the task, so the challenges are, in my view, essentially identical

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 119 bytes

```python
print(*[str(i)+'*'*(p(i-2)|p(i+2))for i in range(2,int(input()))if(p:=lambda x:all(x%i for i in range(2,x))*(x>1))(i)])
```

Reads from stdin.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc1BCsIwEEbhq2QjnT9VaONGCnqR4iKi1YE4HcYUInj3WNeu3urj6Ts/Ztkf1GpVY8nkx1c2YrSNbzwp8S7gs6YNwDSbY8fiLMr9RmH7Ayy6ZALAE@lwTPF5uUZXhpgSlQ27P1QAT@XUA@vmjFr7rvsC)

Comment: Updated to do that, but in general on this site a function is a valid form of IO.