# Primes and Twin Primes

Tags: code-golf

Your challenge is to write a program to print all the primes (separated by one or more whitespace characters) less than a given integer `N` with an asterisk (`*`) next to each twin prime. A [twin prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) is a prime number that is either two more or two less than another prime.

(Hardcoding outputs is allowed, but it is not likely to result in very short code.)

Shortest code wins!

### Input

- `N` is always one of 50, 100, 1000, 1000000, or 10000000

### Output

- The output for input `50` should be

  ```
  2 3* 5* 7* 11* 13* 17* 19* 23 29* 31* 37 41* 43* 47
  ```

Comment: I think you should get rid of the restrictions for N.

Comment: @rak1507 Those restrictions can be used to make your code shorter, but you can solve the general problem too.

Comment: As the inputs are finite and fixed, I suggest you include the expected outputs for all 5

Comment: @user101295 I doubt any solution that works for those inputs will not work for all N.

Comment: @rak1507 If that is the case, the restrictions would not matter, right?

Comment: Are we allowed to have a space after the prime, before its asterisk?

Comment: @Adám No, but you can have as much whitespace between the numbers as you want.

Comment: @user101295 yes, which makes the restrictions unnecessary

Comment: @rak1507 I'm just leaving it there to see if there are any solutions that can make use of it.

Comment: ok, fair enough

Comment: @rak1507 The restrictions are actually useful: With those specific Ns, you never need to compute if N+1 is prime.

Comment: @Adám do you mean n+2? I don't think that's right, because for 11 for example, to check if 11 is a twin prime, you have to check n-2 (no), and n+2 (yes)

Comment: @rak1507 N is always even (and>2) so N cannot be a prime. The last prime candidate is N-1 so you only would need to check N+1 if it wasn't for this restriction telling you that N+1 never would be a prime.

Comment: True, but I would be surprised if that saves any characters

Comment: Are we allowed to let the asterisks count neighbouring primes, e.g. `5**`?

Comment: @Adám No, there should be exactly one asterisk next to each twin prime in the output.

Comment: @rak1507 Only having to work for these specific case has saved me at least 4 bytes in my Python answer, the fact that they are all composite (and larger than `2`) is definitely useful.

Comment: May the amount of whitespace separating the entries vary? EDIT I see "No, but you can have as much whitespace between the numbers as you want" - please consider updating the post.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I have updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper) with a different way to detect if `k-2` is a prime which works with `k=2`.

Uses [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) for the primality tests and the fact that \$p\$, \$p+1\$ and \$p+2\$ are coprime for most primes \$p\$.

```python
P=k=q=1
exec"if P%k:print`k`+'*'[k<3:P%(k+2)|q/k];q=k+2\nP*=k*k;k+=1\n"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8A227bQ1pArtSI1WSkzTSFANduqoCgzryQhO0FbXUs9OtvG2CpAVSNb20izplA/O9a60BbIjskL0LLN1sq2zta2NYzJU9LKzCsoLdHQ/P/f0MDAAAA)

The output includes the input if it is prime, but this is fine since all testcases are composite.

### How?

We use the following result of Wilson's theorem:

$$
(k-1)!^2 \operatorname{mod} k = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $k$ is prime}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

In the code `P` is used to keep track of \$(k-1)!^2\$ and `P%k` tests if `k` is a prime.
If this is the case, we print the output and update `q` to `k+2`.
If `k==q` at the `print` statement, we know that `k-2` was a prime and `k` is a twin prime.

`P%(k+2)` tests if `k+2` is a prime number. If we would use the exact same prime test as before, this would be `P*k*k*(k+1)*(k+1)%(k+2)`, but with our assumption that \$k\$, \$k+1\$ and \$k+2\$ are coprime for prime \$k\$, this gives the same result.
The assumption doesn't hold for `k=2`, but this is handled separately with `'*'[k<3:]`, which results in the empty string if `k<3`.

Comment: Love the `input('2\n')` construction!

Comment: +1 for Wilson's theorem.

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcbRCkAwFAbge08hJWwXjDucd9g9Somsv45NU5R3H9/VZx@/H1yHoAnkSEXrvS6J2WKdorWnYT9jlpnIBvRNq9Mcsi5eV2LqHP0fWQuCQAdJauREGLaXz4sQVFV9)

Comment: From comments (at the moment) we may use as much whitespace as we like, assuming this means we can vary it you can do [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8A227bQ1pArtSI1WamgKDOvRCMhO0FbXUs9OtvG2CpAVSNb20izplA/O1ZTSyNANVvTutAWKGQdoGWbrZVtna1ta2itpJWZV1BaoqH5/7@pAQA) (or less?).

Comment: @JonathanAllan there might be some way to abuse the flexibility, but your proposed version marks all primes `>2` as twin primes, as `q` should only be updated if `k` is prime.

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that, yep; less likely to be able to save bytes then.

Comment: Can't you save the square in Wilson's formula? You're  not using =1, all you need is !=0, (anything that evaluates to True) right?

Comment: @Albert.Lang Without the square \$4\$ is recognized as a prime number, as \$3!%4=2\$.

Comment: Oh, nasty! But that's the only one isn't it? Perhaps one can somehow work around it? Might be difficult, though, if we only have a single byte to play with.

Comment: @Albert.Lang That's what I thought as well, see my previous 81 byter in the [revision history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/219992/revisions). But now that we don't have an additional special case for `k=2` anymore, I don't it is possible to save bytes by removing the square.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is used to compute primes. The main advantage here is its incredible speed (`N=10000000` is computed in just a few seconds).

```python
n=input()
R=range(n)
for k in R:
 if k>1:R[k+k::k]=(n+~k)/k*[0];print`k`+'*'[:R[k-2]|R[k+2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCsMgEADQ3a@4LRoJUUeL/QhXOUiGppWDi4gdCiW/bgh58yu/9tnZ9c4hc/k2qUQMdeX3S7IS216BIDNELyBvQE/rYyJN3hMGyfogNdOYDD5KzdwWWvQwDulKk8P/dR1i79bcTg)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
ÆRµ+Ø+Ḥ¤ẒẸ”*xṭ)K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//w4ZSwrUrw5gr4bikwqThupLhurjigJ0qeOG5rSlL////NTA)

### How it works

```
ÆRµ+Ø+Ḥ¤ẒẸ”*xṭ)K - Main link. Takes N on the left
ÆR               - Yield the prime range until N
  µ           )  - Over each prime P between 2 and N:
       ¤         -   Group into a nilad:
    Ø+           -     Builtin; [1, -1]
      Ḥ          -     Unhalve; [2, -2]
   +             -   Add to P;  [P+2, P-2]
        Ẓ        -   Is prime?
         Ẹ       -   Are any true? Either 1 or 0
          ”*x    -   Repeat "*" that many times
             ṭ   -   Append to P, yielding [P, "*"] or [P, ""]
               K - Join by spaces
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>32</s> 26 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
(⍕,⍬⍴'*'/⍨1⍭¯2 2+⊢)⍤0∘⍸1⍭⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X@NR71SdR71rHvVuUddS13/Uu8LwUe/aQ@uNFIy0H3Ut0nzUu8TgUceMR707QOKPejf/T3vUNuFRb9@jrmaItkPrjR@1TXzUNzU4yBlIhnh4Bv9PUzA1AAA)

`⍳` **ɩ**ntegers 1 through `N`

`1⍭` Boolean mask indicating those that are primes

`⍸` `⍳` **ɩ**ndices of the trues (i.e. the primes)

`∘` then

`(`…`)∘0` on each scalar, apply the following tacit function:

`⊢` the argument

`¯2 2+` add `[-2,2]` to that

`1⍭` indicate the primes

`'*'/⍨` use that to replicate an asterisk (gives `""` or `"*"` or `"**"`)

`⍬⍴` **r**eshape into a scalar (lit. an array with an empty shape; gives `' '` or `'*'` or `'*'`)

`⍕,` prepend the string representation of the argument prime

since the inner function mapped scalars to vectors the overall result is a matrix

Comment: Would testing the existence of 2 in absolute difference to the precomputed primes save some? (Like in [my Jelly submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219999/53748).)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Good idea, but I can't seem to [get it any shorter](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X@NR79RHHTMe9a7SUddST4h51LvC6FHHCj1boGANEOvpAkU0wSp2GD7qXfuod/P/tEdtEx719j3qan7Uu@ZR75ZD640ftU181Dc1OMgZSIZ4eAb/T1MwNQAA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online").

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆRðȮạe@2”*xṄ)
```

A monadic Link that accepts a number and prints the output with a new-line separator.
Uses the fact we never receive input, \$n\$, such that \$n-1\$ or \$n\$ are only on the lower side of a prime pair
(e.g. \$41\$ or \$42\$, which would miss the `*` from \$41\$).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9DhDSfWPdy1MNXB6FHDXK2KhztbNP8fbj@x/FHDHKDA//@mBgA)** (footer suppresses Link's return value).

#### How?

```
ÆRðȮạe@2”*xṄ) - Link: n
ÆR            - primes in [2,n] (call this "Primes")
  ð         ) - for each (p in Primes) do this f(p, Primes):
   Ȯ          -   print p (plus no newline)
    ạ         -   (p) absolute difference (Primes)
       2      -   two
     e@       -   (two) exists in (the absolute differences)?
        ”*    -   '*' character
          x   -   ('*') times (existence of two)
           Ṅ  -   print that (plus a newline)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 41 bytes

```
[:(,&":"0' *'{~1+./@p:2 _2+/])i.&.(p:inv)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o600dNSUrJQM1BW01KvrDLX19B0KrIwU4o209WM1M/XU9DQKrDLzyjT/a3KlJmfkK6QpmBpAWOq6urrqMEFDA4P/AA)

### how

- `i.&.(p:inv)` Returns every prime less than or equal to the input.
- `2 _2+/]` Create a 2 row table, adding and substracting 2 to each prime.  Eg,
  for n=50:

  ```
  4 5 7 9 13 15 19 21 25 31 33 39 43 45 49
  0 1 3 5  9 11 15 17 21 27 29 35 39 41 45
  ```
- `1...p:` Is each a prime?

  ```
  0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
  ```
- `+.` Reduce each column by "or":

  ```
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
  ```

  This mask tells which are the twin primes.
- `' *'{~` Convert 1 to `*` and 0 to  .
- `,&":"0` For each, append `,` to the input after converting to string `&":"0`:

  ```
  2  
  3* 
  5* 
  7* 
  11*
  13*
  17*
  19*
  23 
  29*
  31*
  37 
  41*
  43*
  47
  ```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 70 bytes

```
If[FreeQ[NextPrime[a=Prime@#,{-1,1}]-a,2|-2],a,a""]&/@Range@PrimePi@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zMt2q0oNTUw2i@1oiSgKDM3NTrRFkw7KOtU6xrqGNbG6ibqGNXoGsXqJOokKinFquk7BCXmpac6gJUFZDooq/0HMvNKHNKjDQ0MDGL//wcA)

-1 byte from @att

Comment: Nice trick with multiplication, but I think it should be outputting for all primes up to N, not outputting for only the Nth prime.

Comment: `FreeQ[NextPrime[a=Prime@#,{-1,1}]-a,2|-2]` also saves one byte

Comment: @att yes, you are right. Many of us agree that those restrictions for N were not necessary....

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 107 bytes

```python
p=lambda x:0<all(x%i for i in range(2,x))<x
f=lambda n:[str(i)+'*'*(p(i-2)|p(i+2))for i in range(2,n)if p(i)]
```

Subtracted 2 bytes for f=

A port of my solution to the previous challenge, with a slightly better p function.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYuxCgIxEAV7v2IbuX05hSMiyHF@iVhENLoQ98KaIoL/Hq@xsppiZvK7PGbdHbK1lo8pPC/XQHUcppAS17VQnI2ERMmC3m/sNxWY6ir@Wh1Pr2Is6DvXOc4sW4/Pgt4Df7NCIi0S55ZNtLCLvB@A9gU)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>136</s> 119 bytes

```
n=>(a=(R=n=>[...Array(n).keys()])(n)).filter(x=>a[~x]=+R(x).filter(y=>x%y<1)).map(x=>x+" *"[a[~x+2]|a[~x-2]]).join(' ')
```

```js
f=
n=>(a=(R=n=>[...Array(n).keys()])(n)).filter(x=>a[~x]=+R(x).filter(y=>x%y<1)).map(x=>x+" *"[a[~x+2]|a[~x-2]]).join(' ')
console.log(f(100));
```

*Saved 17 bytes thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718)*

Comment: `(a=[...Array(n).keys()])` => `(a=(R=n=>[...Array(n).keys()])(n))`; `x=>a[~x]=[...Array(x+1).keys()].filter(y=>x%y<1).length==2` => `x=>a[~x]=R(x+1).filter(y=>x%y<1).length==2` => `x=>a[~x]=+R(x).filter(y=>x%y<1)`

Comment: @tsh Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>81</s>  80 bytes

A port of [ovs' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219992/58563). Expects a BigInt.

```javascript
n=>{for(s=p=k=2n;k<n;p*=k++)p%k?s+=' '+(x=k-2n,p/x%x+p%~-~k?k+'*':k):0;return s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDsIgEADAr/RCgCKKPZaufUtTweg2ywaqITH26zjzWj5LWfOTd0vpHlqERnD7xpRVAQaEgTxO5LkHNEazwLkYkJ00qgLagU58qaIaFoc9cEYjezmiHp3PYX9n6sqvrYlK2sJ5Sw8V1dU5R1q3Pw)

Or **77 bytes** with `eval()`, as suggested by @EliteDaMyth:

```javascript
n=>eval("for(s=p=k=2n;k<n;p*=k++)p%k?s+=' '+(x=k-2n,p/x%x+p%~-~k?k+'*':k):s")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRDoMgDADQqywmBLBjY37qOs9CHCxbTWnEGL68OnvvF45Qlu0ru@P8ji1hY3zFI6ymS3kzBQUJB57oyZP0SABWFM0FUF80mIrkBr7KvaoKok530kygez2SHUtn25K55DXe1vwxyTy892xt@wM)

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 91 bytes

```javascript
n=>{for(k=1;++k<n;)(g=d=>{for(i=d;i%--d;);return~-d})(i=k)||print(g(i-=2)*g(i+=4)?k:k+'*')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcjBCsIwDADQr5ElK4FOPIgx7luGtaMG6oh1F7f9et3B04P3HObhfbc0FZrPNUrNcvvGl4FKx87pNTPCKOG/SQKnA1FgZHuUj@WNwor7Ky7LZCkXGCGRHLHddXLCXi/qmrbBtUbovPdYfw)

Comment: [81 -> 80 with eval](https://tio.run/##BcFBDsIgEADAr5gmZKGIYo/FtW8hFYwuWUhpGk79Os78/OHrun3Lbji/Q4/YGV/h8EkOMW@yYkHCiR092ZURSWtVBC1VI1xAk5YNyUx8Lfcmmi7iNCctMMIMoGbr6qD6mrnmFG4pf2SUD2stK9X/)

Comment: @EliteDaMyth Thanks. I saved a few more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), `-S` 32 bytes

```
o fj
äÏ-X¥2Ãp0
íVíVé '+ Ï?X+'*:X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P18hLYvr8JLD/boRh5YaHW4uMOA6vDYMhFYqqGsrHO63j9BW17KK@P/f1EBBNxgA)

Notably, this works for the required inputs, but not a few others like 12.

Explanation:

```
o fj    
o       # Create the range [0 ... input]
  fj    # Keep only the primes
        # Store as U


äÏ-X¥2Ãp0    
ä     Ã      # Create an array by mapping each pair in U through:
 Ï-X         #  Get the difference
    ¥2       #  Check whether it's 2
       p0    # Add 0 to the end of that array
             # Store as V


íVíVé '+ Ï?X+'*:X    #
   Vé                # Rotate V 1 item to the right
 Ví   '+             # Add each item in rotated V with the same index in original V
í                    # For each item in U:
         Ï?          #  If the same index in V is not 0:
           X+'*      #   Add "*" to it
               :X    #  Otherwise don't change it
                     # Implicit output, -S flag joins with spaces
```

I feel like there's a better way to accomplish `Ï?X+'*:X` but I haven't found one

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 172 bytes

```powershell
$L=@{};($N=2.."$args")|%{$c=2;$k=$_
for(;($k*$c)-le$N[-1]){if(!($L|% c*y($k*$c))){$L[$k*$c]=1};$c++}}
$x=$N|?{!$l.$_}
$x|%{if((($_+2)-in$x)-or(($_-2)-in$x)){"$_*"}else{$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCoMwFET3PUUNI@QrEXUroT2AeAGRUCS2YqhFF7XEnD1NS7ubx8xjHvNTL@tNG@M9anm2ruJoZJllDJflujLaY4telhUmCXUY5oWHxZSgJ2E0mlYUHdlx4BFHvcfHPnn9aiKLuv3mThauQp@mzh2wSTT7yUYwGdSHw0PwOYdKSxLjHRuJcBNY/Jksg0qY02bVNljOe1/kef4G)

Thanks to @mazzy for ~70 bytes

Comment: nice try. Wasif, 1) you can write `"$_"` instead `"$($_)"`; 2) you use `1` for a prime number and `0` for a composite. Flip: `0` (or `$null`) for prime and `1` for composite. Then you don't need to fill the hashtable `$L`

Comment: @mazzy thank you for the tips. But I am unable to implement your 2nd suggestion using arrays :-(

Comment: [Wasif's solution with flipped prime flag](https://tio.run/##NY1BCoMwFET3PUUNI@QrEXUroT2AeAGRUCS2YqhFF7XEnD1NS7ubx8xjHvNTL@tNG@M9anm2ruJoZJllDJflujLaY4telhUmCXUY5oWHxZSgJ2E0mlYUHdlx4BFHvcfHPnn9aiKLuv3mThauQp@mzh2wSTT7yUYwGdSHw0PwOYdKSxLjHRuJcBNY/Jksg0qY02bVNljOe1/kef4G "PowerShell – Try It Online") :) you can shorten this code even more. For example, you can use an array instead the hashtable `$L`.

Comment: @mazzy you are so nice, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 91 bytes

Inspired by [Wasif](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220011/80745)

```powershell
($x=($N=2.."$args")|?{!($N-lt($c=$_)|?{!($c%$_)})})|%{"$_"+'*'*(($_+2)-in$x-or($_-2)-in$x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYhBCoAgEADfkqy0JkZ5l37QFyQiKpAKDRLKt28eZC4zc53P4sO2OEeEEA3CaHTbMpj8Gpj4hrfKS7kbYTZgy5h51pT5@MvAMlk3dYMIVmqh9gOiOn0uVUokIuq77gc)

The script outputs correctly for the allowed input and incorrectly in the general case (see last twins for 12)

Less golfed:

```powershell
$Numbers = 2.."$args"
$primes = $Numbers | Where {
    $current = $_
    $dividers = $Numbers -lt $current | Where {($current % $_) -eq 0}
    !$dividers       # true if the $current is a prime
}
$primes | ForEach {
    "$_"+'*'*(($_+2) -in $primes -or ($_-2) -in $primes)    # format output number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 61 bytes

I'm using Julia 0.4 because `primes` was a built-in 
It works with a more recent version of Julia and the package `Primes.jl`

This approach will fail sometimes when `N` or `N-1` is prime, which isn't the case for any of the requested inputs

```julia
x->map(i->print(" $i"*"*"^(i+2∈p||i-2∈p)),(p=primes(x);))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8n2b7v0LXLjexQCNT166gKDOvRENJQSVTSQsI4zQytY0edXQU1NRk6oIZmpo6GgW2QGW5qcUaFZrWmpr/0zRMDTS5wDpz8jSQWWkahgYQoPkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 101 bytes

```perl
@p[grep"".(1x$_)!~/^(11+)\1+$/,2..$_]=(1)x$_; 
$_=join$",map$p[$_-2]+$p[$_+2]?"$_*":$_,grep$p[$_],2..@p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxLCsIwEEDPYphFYj7NBLpRir2AJ6hxcFGkUpuhirjy6I62u8d78Lifx1qk5e4696xU0PgGMptPddaI1pzQQuVSCEC50Wj@cQ/U3MowgXL3CwN3QD5lu4JN@aCAtmoH5JbjavMyaFkEY4zfws@hTA/xx1cdMIrnHw)

Uses the somewhat known `/^(11+)\1+$/` regexp to detect primes.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>99</s> 87 bytes

With some help from [Robin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder) and improvements from [Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen):

```r
for(n in 2:scan())if(sum(!n%%2:n)<2)cat("
",n,"*"[sum(!n%%2:n-2)==1|!sum(!(n+2)%%2:n)])
```

or, when detailed:

```r
for(n in 2:scan()) #range
  if(sum(!n%%2:n)<2)#prime number
    cat(" #create space
    ",n, #print n
    "*"[sum(!n%%2:n-2)==1| #print * for previous prime
    !s(!(n+2)%%2:n)]} # or for next prime
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNPITNPwciqODkxT0NTMzNNo7g0V0MxT1XVyCpP08ZIMzmxREOJS0knT0dJSykaSVLXSNPW1rBGESykkadtpAnRE6v539TA4D8A)

Comment: Both versions seem to omit the ```*```s on 3, 11, 17, 29, and so on... (the twin primes that are two *less* than another prime)

Comment: Ah, correct, I had misread the question!!!

Comment: [94 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNPITNPwciqODkxT0NTMzNNo7g0V0MxT1XVyCpP08ZIMzmxRENJQUknT0dJSykaSVLXSNPW1rBGESykkadtpAnRE6tTnFpgq6Sk@d/UwOA/AA)... or [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNPITNPwciqODkxT0NTMzNNo7g0V0MxT1XVyCpP08ZIMzmxREOJS0knT0dJSykaSVLXSNPW1rBGESykkadtpAnRE6v539TA4D8A) with a space between each twin-prime and the asterisk next to it...

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Razetime*

```
m?o`:'*ssȯ#2`m₁¹≠₁
fṗḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P9c@P8FKXau4@MR6ZaOE3EdNjYd2PupcAKS50h7unP5wx@L///8bGhgYAAA)

[Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) doesn't particularly like mixing numerics + characters.

```
fṗḣ                   # helper function: primes up to input
m?o`:'*ssȯ#2`m₁¹oa-₁  # main function:
m                  ₁  # for each element in primes up to input
                oa-   # get the absolute differences to 
            `m₁¹      # all primes up to input
         ȯ#2          # and count how many '2's there are:
 ?                    # if it's zero
        s             # convert it to a string
  o`:'*s              # otherwise convert it to a string & prepend with '*'
```

Comment: `≠` can be used for absolute difference.

Comment: @Razetime - Thanks!  I *kinda* knew there was that command, but somehow just couldn't remember what it was...

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```r
p=2;for(y in 3:scan())p=c(p,y[sum(!y%%2:y)<2]);for(z in p)cat(z,"*"[2%in%abs(z-p)]," ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCoAgEADAr5gg7IaB2a3yJeHBhKBDtmQd1s8bNee5aiVnp@28gMWexDDmGBIgkotAmpf8HNCwUnZknK3Hv5avEsZwQ9GylYtVe1JhzVA6Qq@lkFh7Y@oL)

I wanted to try a different approach to [Xi'an's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220055/95126)...

<s>Frustratingly, though, after golfing & golfing I still can't get rid of that last pesky byte...</s> Got it!

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 54 bytes

```
{put map {$_~'*'x?is-prime $_+(2|-2)if .is-prime},^$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/uqC0RCE3sUChWiW@Tl1LvcI@s1i3oCgzN1VBJV5bw6hG10gzM01BDyZaqxOnEl/7P03D0MBA8z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/index.html), 88 bytes

Added 14 bytes to fix an error kindly pointed out by [Kjetil S](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64733/kjetil-s).

```python
def f(n,b=1,c=2):
 while c<n:a,b,c=b,c,Primes().next(c);print(str(b)+'*'[:2in(b-a,c-b)])
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwNyLEOQDAQANC9X9HNHUeQWIp_sIvBVRtNuEg14fMZ3vI257UHIR4bsmOLRulnD4fTdhCzEv_5oymG092Albg3gcX-ikES3CkCY5Hl2WzaIMDlSrZkXFApD12NH1NMG38=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: All primes 3-19 should have * according to the challenge since they have a prime neighbor just 2 away.

Comment: @KjetilS. Fixed - thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 25 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
o fj
äÏ-X¥2
gVí|Vé)ð²_+'*
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=byBmagrkzy1YpTIKZ1btfFbpKfCyXysnKg&input=NTA)

```
o fj       - primes up to N
äÏ-X¥2     - difference of each consecutive primes == 2?
g ... _+'* - add an asterisk to the elements at the indexes obtained with @ :
Ví|Vé)   @ pair array with array rotated then reduce by OR
ð²       @ truthy values when passed trough f(square)

-S flag to join with spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅPÐδα2δå'*×øJ»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9vc2FiaWX//8OFUMOQzrTOsTLOtMOlJyrDl8O4SsK7//81MA)

Or alternatively:

```
ÅP©ε?®yα2å'*×,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//8OFUMKpzrU/wq55zrEyw6UnKsOXLP//NTD/LS1uby1sYXp5)

Or alternatively (only works in [the legacy version of 05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b)):

```
ÅPÐδα2QOĀ'*×+»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v8wNWFiMWX//8OFUMOQzrTOsTJRT8SAJyrDlyvCu///NTA)

All three programs above output newline-delimited.
I have the feeling a 13-byter is possible, but I'm unable to find it thus far.

**Explanation:**

```python
ÅP              # Push a list of primes in the range [2, (implicit) input-integer]
  Ð             # Triplicate this list
   δ            # Pop two of them, and apply double-vectorized:
    α           #  For each prime, get its absolute difference with the list of primes
      δ         # For each list of absolute differences:
     2 å        #  Check if a 2 is among them (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
        '*×    '# Repeat "*" that amount of times as string
           ø    # Create pairs with the remaining list of primes
            J   # Join each pair together to a string
             »  # Join this list by newlines
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)

ÅP              # Push a list of primes in the range [2, (implicit) input-integer]
  ©             # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
   ε            # For-each over each prime:
    ?           #  Pop and print the prime (without trailing newline)
     ®          #  Push the prime-list from variable `®`
      yα        #  Get for each its absolute difference with the current prime `y`
        2å      #  Check if a 2 is in this list of absolute differences
          '*×  '#  Repeat "*" that amount of times as string
             ,  #  Pop and print this string with trailing newline

ÅPÐδα           # Similar as in the first program above
     2Q         # Check for each inner-most value if it's equal to 2
       O        # Sum all inner list of checks
        Ā       # Check which sums are >= 1
         '*×   '# For each, repeat "*" that amount of times as string
            +   # Append it to each integer in the remaining list of primes
             »  # Join this list by newlines
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>108</s> 106 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```
f(n,i,j,d,e){for(d=e=i=2;j=n>i;j/i?printf(i-d-2?" %d":d-e-2?"* %d*":" %d*",i),e=d,d=i:1,i++)for(;i%++j;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LDoIwEEXX8BVNDaaFwQeJG2rhW7BTYAgWA@iG8O1Y3Lm6Z84kd8akjTHbgZzp32jZfZqRhlNbhH@qp4d3Wy0cEHSAYOVSD6NAbTXpTHXaFaS6M5WvkdxcC0oxzUrOIuQ5pnbn2A8xz/kvgCRYjYCa8itQksi9TlGUJJ2Sat18C3tW5MQO1dgYYKatxjj2/JHhEgb7wqkwmEzlasH9JWBHJ73xb/pYt9vlCw)

The only input parameter which the function requires is n. The hardest part was avoiding duplication of * after numbers, and there ought to be a better way to do that.